# Store an array using MongoDB and Java

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb

I am saving a BasicDBObject in my mongoDb collection

```
BasicDBObject[] aBox = new BasicDBObject[5];
BasicDBObject obj = new BasicDBObject();
obj.append("box", aBox);
```

for the moment this is a void array so I have just [] in my collection

but when I am trying to get my array

```
DBObject[] aBox = (DBObject[]) obj.get("box");
```

I have this error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mongodb.BasicDBList cannot be cast to [Lcom.mongodb.DBObject;
```

Do you know how to have my array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BasicBDList` is a `List` and therefore has a `toArray` method. Or you could just keep it as a list. Something like this should work:

```
List<BasicDBObject> list = (List<BasicDBObject>) obj.get("box");
BasicDBObject[] aBox = list.toArray(new BasicDBObject[list.size()]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, s I can also directly save list I have not to convert to array before saving